# how to measure the speed of mobile broadband traffic on 3g or wifi cell programmatically on the iphone

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

In my app, I am already doing the collection of traffic on iphone,
Now need to check how to measure the speed of mobile broadband traffic on 3g or wifi cell programmatically.

For example:
Every 1 minute or 10 minutes, or more...., need to know what is the average speed that data is being delivered to both download and upload, both the wifi network as the 3G / 4G cellular.

Please, does anyone know how to do this on the iphone?

Comment: You could do what the bandwidth test apps do and download a file of some known size and measure it yourself.  Those apps tend to report ping , latency and speed. You might add in DNS lookup time as well or use a fixed IP for your test.